# Access VBA Run-time error 3129

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I can not find my Problem. It always throws out an Run-time error 3129 and I did not found any help in the web.

```vb
Dim strSQL As String

sqlList.AddItem strSQL = "SELECT Firma FROM Firma_Daten"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: What is sqlList?

Comment: You can't `AddItem` on a `String`, a `String` isn't some collection you can add things to.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments, you can populate your listbox using something like:

```
sqlList.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
sqlList.RowSource = "SELECT Firma FROM Firma_Daten"
```

Where `sqlList` is the name of your listbox.

Answer (score -1):

Should be:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Firma FROM Firma_Daten"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Yes, this would need to be an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE

Comment: so what should i need to use if I want to get the Items in an Listbox

Comment: You should delete this answer.

Comment: You can add the SQL statement as the RowSource of the ListBox directly in design mode. This is the easiest approach. You can also dimension your SQL statement as a recordset, iterate through it, and then add the items to the ListBox one at a time.